# mysql join performance IF multiple OR conditions

Tags: mysql, performance, networking, join

I hold a set of nodes in one mysql table1 and a table of edges in another one (table2). Nodes come with primary keys and edges use this "foreign key"

```
**table1**
id label
1  node1
2  node2
3  node3

**table2**
FK_first FK_sec   rel
1        3        guardian
2        1        guardian
1        3        times
```

I know the db-design is not perfect, but its simple...
Now i want the number of 'rel' for every node and do a query like:

```
SELECT 
  label, 
  COUNT( rel ) as freq
FROM
  `table1` 
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON (id=FK_first OR id=FK_second) 
GROUP BY label
ORDER BY freq DESC
```

I have about 1000 nodes and 2000 edges. A query with ON (id=FK_first  <strike>OR id=FK_second</strike>), then the query is way faster (<1 sec). The other query needs about 6 sec which is ver slow.
I would appreciate some comments to speed this up a bit :-)

1. LEFT JOIN table2 ON (id=FK_first OR id=FK_second)   ~6 sec
2. LEFT JOIN table2 ON (id=FK_first)                   ~0.16 sec
3. LEFT JOIN table2 ON (id=FK_second)                  ~0.16 sec
4. LEFT JOIN table2 ON id IN (FK_first,FK_second)      ~6 sec

```
EXPLAIN 1:
        id  select_type table   type    possible_keys                   key key_len ref rows    Extra
        1   SIMPLE          table1  ALL NULL                            NULL    NULL    NULL    2571    Using temporary; Using filesort
        1   SIMPLE          table2  ALL FK_first,FK_second,FK_first_2   NULL    NULL    NULL    3858    

EXPLAIN 2:
id  select_type  table  type   possible_keys       key    key_len ref        rows   Extra
1   SIMPLE       table1 index  NULL                PRIMARY    2   NULL       2571   Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE       table2 ref   FK_first,FK_first_2  FK_first_2 4   table1.id  1
```

Comment: Do you have an index on `FK_second`?

Comment: @Michael: considering that the last paragraph is far from clear, we should ask him whether he has an index on the key used in the query without or.

Comment: i was with you until the actual question... can you show the 2 queries? describe your indexing?

Comment: yes, I have a index for FK_First and another one for FK_second as well as a combination of both...

Comment: To make it more clear:
LEFT JOIN table2 ON (id=FK_first OR id=FK_second) ~6 sec
LEFT JOIN table2 ON (id=FK_first)                 ~0.16 sec
LEFT JOIN table2 ON (id=FK_second)                ~0.16 sec

Comment: `ON id IN (FK_first, FK_second)`?

Comment: LEFT JOIN table2 ON id IN (FK_first,FK_second)      ~6 sec
same speed...

Comment: Can you show the EXPLAIN for the queries?

Comment: Table 1 doesn't appear to have an index on ID.

Comment: We get closer to this. As you see in EXPLAIN 2, primary_key is used now. Strange that its not used in EXPLAIN 1.
@NevilleK id is the primary key

Comment: That's really weird - it doesn't even recognize there is a primary key in EXPLAIN1. Can you reverse the query - i.e. selecting from table 2 and joining to table 1?

Comment: This slows it down to ~18secs

Comment: Could you use SHOW CREATE to give the table structures? As long as you have an index on FK_sec, my guess would be that the query optimizer is ignoring indexes b/c it estimates the indexes are pointing to too many rows in table2 for the index to be useful.

Comment: It's worth running http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimize-table.html on the two tables....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing two joins and moving the "OR" into the COUNT() function:

For every row, this joins table2 once on FK1, then again on FK2 (if it is not already joined to that row via FK1. Then in the COUNT, we specify that only rows which have either join's rel column as non-null.

```
SELECT 
  label, 
  COUNT( table2A.rel || table2B.rel ) as freq
FROM
  `table1` 
  LEFT JOIN 
    table2 as table2A 
    ON id=table2A.FK_first
  LEFT JOIN 
    table2 as table2B 
    ON id=table2B.FK_second 
    AND  table2A.FKFirst != table2B.FKFirst
GROUP BY label
ORDER BY freq DESC
```

Comment: This speeds it up to ~2sec, but its very complicated and not fast enough in my opinion...

Comment: Look at the EXPLAIN on this solution. I think this is the right approach to take. The remaining slowness might be due to the filesort needed by the GROUP/ORDER. So (1) try indexing 'label' since you're grouping on it. (2) Try increasing @@max_heap_table_size and @@tmp_table_size, especially if you see a thread state of "converting HEAP to MyISAM" or "copying to tmp table on disk" during execution. (I don't think your resultset could be large enough to trigger this, though.)

Comment: Yes, you are right! After I used the id and not label to group it was very fast. Thank you all for helping to find the solution!

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer to reflect the final solution you ended up using if it was based on this logic, so that in the future anyone who finds this question sees clearly what the final solution was :-)

Comment: hey what if someone is in the same situation but using the `INNER join` instead of the `left join`, splitting into 2 joins wont work in that case, right ?

Comment: Right, I don't think that will work... If you do an inner join, I expect you wouldn't get any results unless you had an edge row where a node was pointing to itself. 10 years on, I could be glossing over something here so take it with a grain of salt. Another technique that could be explored is doing 2 simple count aggregations on the edge table in subqueries and joining that to node table for the labels.

Comment: Something like (select FK1, count(*) as qty from t2) as LHS as the subquery (same for FK2, RHS), then the outer query would be SELECT label, LHS.qty as freq_left, RHS.qty as freq_right, LHS.qty + RHS.qty as total_freq